# BroadcastReceiver, SMS_RECEIVE, abort from service

Tags: android, sms, broadcastreceiver

I wanted to created a SMS BlackLister app to learn Android SDK, so I created my BroadCastReceiver extended class.
My app retrieves the Country Number of the incoming message, and compares it to the ones contains in my database (this is quit a simple process), but I read that long process shouldn't be called from a BroadCastReceiver this is why I created a class extended from IntentService, which is supposed to do all the background jobs (compare with the content of the database, and so on), but I can't abort the broadcast from this IntentService, and therefore can't intercept the SMS before the others apps.

I have no idea of how I could find a workaround, if you need to see my class, here it is :

```
package com.example.smslistener;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;

public class SmsReceived extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent arg1) {
        final Object[] my = (Object[])arg1.getExtras().get("pdus");
        for(int i=0; i < my.length; i++){
            SmsMessage message = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])my[i]);
            String number = message.getOriginatingAddress();
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, SmsWorker.class);
            intent.putExtra("number", number);
            context.startService(intent);
        }
    }
}
```

Could you help me, thank !

Comment: That's quite tricky. I don't think you can do it that way... When you start the IntentService from the broadcast then your broadcast is finished so there isn't any way to get canceled by the IntentService, its already finished.

Comment: Ok thank I was right thinking I couldn't do it with an Intent. I move the content of the intent in the BroadCastReceiver, and as my database requests are small, it seems to work well. Unfortunately, all of this will not work with Android Kitkat as AbortBroadCast will not work with SMS, I will have to find another way to do this.

Comment: At KitKat there are many changes in the SMS API. Mainly apps can here about SMS (with read-only permissions to Content Provider) but cannot write to DB unless you are the "Default SMS App" links: 1. https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.4.html#SMS 2. http://android-developers.blogspot.gr/2013/10/getting-your-sms-apps-ready-for-kitkat.html